# How do i make my blockquote responsive to different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive, html-heading, blockquote

I have added a blockquote to the header of my page and am trying to make it responsive so that the text adjusts to the screen size. I would like the text to stay centered, and change size according to the browser.

I have tried changing the font size to `vw` unit.

```css
.container {
  width: 590px;
  margin: 140px auto;
  position: relative;
}

blockquote {
  width: 565px;
  font: 2.65em CallunaRegular;
  letter-spacing: .075em;
  float: left;
  padding: 45px 0 30px 25px;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 2px dotted #858585;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #858585;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.container:before {
  content: "“";
  font-size: 13vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  color: #666;
}

.container:after {
  content: "”";
  font-size: 13vw;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: 150px;
  color: #666;
}

blockquote:first-line {
  font: 1.85em "Sketch Block";
  color: #fff79e;
}

blockquote:first-letter {
  font-size: 2.9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  line-height: .52em;
  margin-right: -18px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

blockquote strong:first-child {
  margin-left: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

blockquote strong:last-child {
  font: 2em "Museo 700";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

blockquote em {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #858585;
}

blockquote+b {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font: 1.6em CallunaRegular;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
}

blockquote+b:first-letter {
  color: #fff79e;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: .25em;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  blockquote:first-letter {
    margin-top: -29px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>
    <article class="container">

      <blockquote>
        <strong>This</strong> Is<em>Just</em> An
        <strong>Example</strong>
      </blockquote>
      <b>Example.</b>
      <a href="#About" class="down-btn">&#8595;</a>
    </article>
  </header>
</div>
```

I expect the blockquote to resize when the browser size is changed.

Comment: It can't be responsive with a fixed width.

Comment: Just change **width: 565px** to **100%** and add **max-width: 565px**. Same goes for the container class. width: 100% and max-width: 590px.

Comment: Thank you @Galanthus, this has worked.

Comment: You are welcome.. Can you upvote / Accept answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Galanthus I am unable to as you wrote the answer as a comment, if you can change it to an answer then i will happily do so. :)

Comment: Thank you, Rianne added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

**width: 565px** to **100%** 
and add **max-width: 565px**.

Same goes for the container class. **width: 100%** and **max-width: 590px**.